# How to close windows after 5 seconds?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

It's 'my' [program](http://pastebin.com/efHb07td). How to close windows after 5 seconds?

```
//...
DeleteObject (hPedzelOkna);

DeleteObject (hBitmapa);

Sleep(5);
PostQuitMessage (0); 

/* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
//...
```

and

```
DestroyWindow(hwnd);
```

not work

(I using Dev C++)

**EDIT** People have suggested using `SetTimer`, however I can't get the following code to work. Could you please a code example showing me how to do this?

```
 SetTimer(hwnd, DestroyWindow(hwnd), 1000, NULL);
```

Answer (score 9):

The Sleep parameter is in milliseconds, so 5 seconds would be 5000, but using Sleep is not the correct approach here (Sleep'ing prevents your window from processing messages)

You should use SetTimer() in WM_CREATE, when the timer fires, call DestroyWindow() on the window

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you almost never want to "Sleep" in a windowed program. If I was doing it, I'd set a timer in response to `WM_CREATE`, and then do the `DestroyWindow`/`PostQuitMessage` in response to `WM_TIMER`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a timer. In windows if you do things like Sleep (that by the way accepts as input a number of milliseconds, not seconds) you are not processing events.

Answer (score 0):

Use SetTimer with a function of NULL. You'll then receive a WM_TIMER message after 1000 milliseconds (ie a second, based on your example).

You then Process the WM_TIMER and send a PostQuitMessage